# This item could not be crawled because the repository did not respond within the specified timeout period

Tags: search, enterprise-search, 2019

In SharePoint 2019 farm when I run full crawl below error keeps appearing in crawl log, I did below actions but still same error.

Error: 
The start address xxxx cannot be crawled.
Context: Application 'Search_Service_Application', Catalog 'Portal_Content'  Details:
This item could not be crawled because the repository did not respond within the specified timeout period.
Try to crawl the repository at a later time, or increase the timeout value on the Proxy and Timeout page in search administration.
You might also want to crawl this repository during off-peak usage times.   (0x80040d7b)

in ULS logs:
object not found for (valueName = ServiceUser ProductKeyName = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\16.0\Search)

Troubleshoot steps that I did:
Given search account Full Permissions and content access account full read permissions from user policy of web application.
Add Host Entry for web application in Crawl servers.
Disable the Loop back check.
Login with content acc account to servers and Internet Options>Connections>LAN settings. Uncheck 'Automatically detect settings'.

Increase the timeout value on the Proxy and Timeout page in search administration. to 120 Seconds

Comment: Anyone got an answer. I now have this error